# Wordpress custom taxonomy with hierachical layout for a specific post

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to pull a posts custom taxonomy into the page. The categories have subcategories and I am struggling to workout how to get the subcategories listed in hierachical way. Currently I am using the below which is showing the categories properly, but they are coming in all jumbled.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'listing_category' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
$categories = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $categories[] = $term->name;
}
$categories_list = join( ", ", $categories ); ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Categories: </strong></td>
        <td><?php  esc_html_e( $categories_list ) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have attempted numerous options but they all seem to be showing all of the categories and subcategories within that custom taxonomy, not only the categories relating to this post.

Any help or guidance would greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41548/get-categories-hierarchical-order-like-wp-list-categories-with-name-slug-li

Answer (score 1):

you should get parent taxonomy and then for every parent get their children
with a loop(foreach).

1- Find the parent taxonomies by this query:

```
$args = array (
         'taxonomy'   => 'listing_category',
         'parent'     => 0,
         'hide_empty' => false
        );
$allTaxParent = get_categories($args);
```

2- Now create a function for get children from parent:

```
function getChildren( $termId=0, $taxonomy='category' ) {
         $children = get_categories( 
                         [
                            'child_of'      => $termId,
                            'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
                            'hide_empty'    => false
                         ]
                      );
        return ($children);
}
```

3- Now you have taxonomies in hierachical way:

```
foreach ( $allTaxParent as $tax ) {

    $children = getChildren($tax->term_id, $tax->taxonomy);

    echo $tax->name . '>';
    foreach ($children as $child){
       echo $child->name . '>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Saeed, unfortunately using this gave no terms at all. Any idea where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Hi, are you sure about your taxonomy in $args? 'listing_category' ?
for example in my product custom post type, taxonomy is 'category-products'

Comment: Also be aware that you will eventually have to print the output as well!
I am editing code number 3 again to display the output